# asp.net mvc default parameter attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to set a default value on a parameter that was not passed, for eg:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {}
```

I'd like to have `page=0` if no page was passed, so I can remove the nullable symbol. I do not want to do this in routing, just on the action itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

New in C# 2010 is the ability for [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)     
{

}
```